# Chi square for pass fail survey test

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, survey

I am trying to perform a statistical test on a survey I did. From my search, I found that Chi-square is the appropriate statistic for such data in the form of pass/fail. The test basically is 3 questions that ask the user to perform 3 tasks on a new product to ensure its accessibility.

**Acceptance Criteria**: For each task, 70% of the users must pass the task.

**Note**: Please Disregard the fact the sample size is small. More test will be performed

The results of the survey are the following

[image]

My questions are the following:

1- Is the Chi-square test appropriate for such data? If not what kind of test could be performed?

2- I know the equation of the Chi-square test, but not sure how to apply it to such data. Could someone explain how to go about it?

3- Could the result be presented in a graphical way? If so, what kind of plot is appropriate?

Thanks,

Comment: You haven't stated any hypotheses. What are you trying to find out?

Comment: Did you mean the confidence interval? p-value?

Comment: Could it be that you want to test whether or not the success proportion for each task differ? Then the null hypothesis would be that all success proportions are equal.The table you have is called a contingency table. There are chi-square tests that can be asymptotically valid. There also are permutation tests like Fisher's exact test that can apply. You should look at books like Alan Agresti's Categorical Data Analysis to understand the subject. You need to know what test(s) you want to use and what assumptions you can make.

Comment: No. Your post says you want to [perform a statistical test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#The_testing_process) (look at steps 1 and 2). There's dozens of things you might test, each corresponding to different null and alternative hypotheses. You have to tell us what it is you want to find out (and strictly, you need to identify your hypothesis before you go off collecting data, so that you're not allowing the [data you collect to influence what you decide to test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testing_hypotheses_suggested_by_the_data))

Comment: Incidentally, if that's the whole of your data you're probably not going to be able to demonstrate anything. (Was there no power-based computation of sample size?)

Comment: I am actually trying to phrase the null and alternative hypotheses. What I am trying to show by the statistical test is Whether this new product is accessible. So these users were asked to performed 3 tasks and pass/fail results were assigned.

Comment: A chi-squared test is not going to tell you about accessibility.  In fact, the very first thing you need to determine is how the answers to these three questions relate to accessibility.  For instance, maybe you would consider the product "accessible" if only a single one of its intended customers can use it; or maybe you need 100% of its intended users to find it accessible? And would a pass on any single question establish its accessibility, or perhaps would a fail on any single question demonstrate is lack of accessibility?

Comment: I see. Disregard the sample size for a moment. Suppose I said that to be accessible, for each task, at least 70% of the users must perform the task correctly. Would that constitute correct acceptance criteria?

Comment: That is a very nice example of the kind of quantitative criterion that can be tested.  If you would edit your post to include that information in it, I would be glad to reopen it (and would look forward to some creative answers!).

Comment: @whuber Edited! Thanks for the patience. I am total new to stats

Comment: Your edit doesn't match the comment that @whuber approved of. 

Why not edit your question to be in ordinary English of what it is you want to find out? Forget that you are talking to statisticians and pretend some friend asked what you are doing.